# How to get grand total in checkout cart in custom cms block?

Tags: magento2

I want to get grand total value in checkout cart page in cms block, I already get value of grand total but when value of grand total changed, grand total value in cms page does not change.

Anyone have any solution? Thanks.

Comment: `cms page does not change`? cms  page?

Comment: what is purpose of getting grand total at cart page cms block?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs even after reloading the page then the block is probably cached. Try to add cacheable="false" to your layout xml.

As it is in the cart page you won't have any problem as there is no full page cache anyway.